# Resources to find editors of magazines and newspapers?

Tags: resources, journalism

I was wondering where I could find editors for atheist essays. I want to see how they write in this field, and what sort of articles tend to be accepted.

It would be very useful!

***Suggestions that this is a duplicate***

If this is a duplicate, the only one supplied did not answer my question. My question is referring to editors of newspapers and magazines. Basically, editors who might be working at the Atlanctic, New York Times, Chicago Tribune, Slate, etc., who are writing and accepting atheist articles. If there is a duplicated question that would give me *this* answer, please refer me to it and I will close this question.

Thanks, guys.

Edit to avoid oddly crude people on this website:
I am not looking for their email or contact information. Here are some examples by what I mean:
Jim Dao is an editor who has written about theological things, and assists in running a blog for the New York Times that is dedicated to this sort of thing. So, one could respond to this question by saying "Jim Dao writes some interesting work at the New York Times, and you might be able to enjoy some of his articles; and he also accepts articles, so you might be able to see what that standard is at the Times." 
Or "Jane Doe is a culture editor over at Slate and she has written many atheist articles. She runs the culture section and hires atheist writers like Christopher Hitchens and Sam Harris, so you may be able to see what sort of articles they write."

Again, I'm not looking for contact information, I'm looking for ideas to write for my own paper at my college. I'm not sure how these editors would hide their massive amounts of work on the internet, and I'm not sure why they'd even try; nor would I understand how they'd hide what articles they accept, and why they'd try.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find an affordable editor?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/2529/how-do-i-find-an-affordable-editor)

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! I think the linked question is a duplicate, too and am voting to close this one as the answers to the other one seem to answer this question. If they are not helpful in your case please [edit] your question to explain why your question is not a duplicate. If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: The question is about finding acquisition editors. The suggested duplicate is about finding developmental editors. They are not duplicates. There are lots of questions about finding markets, all of which have the same basic answer. The answers are the same; the questions are different.

Answer (score 1):

You don't find them. They are hiding from people like you. And from people like me. You might as well announce that you have decided you want to play professional baseball and want to get the names of scouts for the Yankees. It does not work that way. You have to start at the bottom and work your way up.

The places for outsiders to start to find markets and make connections are:

- Publications like Writer's Market and websites like Duotrope that maintain listings of markets that are open to freelance contributors.
- Writers conferences, workshops, and retreats.
- Local and regional publications.

This is true regardless of genre.

You can usually find the names of editors for almost any publication or agency simply by looking at their mastheads, but they are not going to take your calls or read your email. Your emails are going to be read by an intern when they are not busy fetching coffee and it is going to be several steps between that intern and the person who can make a decision.

So, realistically, you are going to have to pay your dues in the minor leagues before you are going to get near any of these editors. The only way to jump the queue is to be famous for something else.

And, frankly, atheism is passe these days. Globalism, populism, and identity are the hot button issues for opinion pieces these days. If you want to make it as an opinion writer then you need to be able to shift your opinions to match the hot topics of the day.

Comment: What? What's with the passive aggression? I'm not looking to write for these editors or contact them... I'm looking to see what they write and what the climate is like. I'm trying to get ideas for my own essays in my college newspaper. I'm not sure why they'd be hiding from people who are trying to read their work. That'd be like Christopher Hitchens hiding his books so people didn't try to write him letters. I'm just asking where I can find editors who write and accept these sort of pieces (i.e., like the religion blog on the nytimes...). No need to jump to conclusions and and attack me.

Comment: @user30132 Well then the answer to your questions is pretty simple. If you want to know what those editors are reading, look at what they are publishing. They tend to accept the kinds of articles they publish.

Comment: That's the problem... I don't know all of the editors at every magazine and paper. I'm looking for resources to find them so I can get ideas. I can't read every section of every newspaper and magazine... and trying to sift through every masthead of every one of them would be futile. Thus the point of my question: are there resources to find specific editors of specific genres?

Comment: Yes, the resources I listed, Writer's Market and Duotrope.